# How to split a environment variable based on delimiter in Docker

Tags: bash, docker, shell, dockerfile

I am trying to split the following string into array on delimiter

```
str="We;Welcome;You;On;Javatpoint"
```

I manage to find a solution in bash that is

> ```
> #!/bin/bash  
> #Example for bash split string by another string  
>   
> str="We;Welcome;You;On;Javatpoint"  
> delimiter=";"  
> s=$str$delimiter  
> array=();  
> while [[ $s ]];  
> do  
> array+=( "${s%%"$delimiter"*}" );  
> s=${s#*"$delimiter"};  
> done;  
> declare -p array
> ```

Results in

> array=([0]="We" [1]="Welcome" [2]="You" [3]="On" [4]="Javatpoint")

I need to split the string into an array inside Dockerfile.

DOCKERFILE:

```
> FROM python:3.7-slim
> 
> ENV IN="We;Welcome;You;On;Javatpoint"
```

Comment: Just for completeness: There are no environment variables involved in your code. I'm not sure whether this affects your docker problem, because you did not show your dockerdefinition.Can't you simply put your shell script into your docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let bash do the splitting.

```
IFS=';' read -r -a array <<<"str"
```

or similar with `readarray` for multiline variables.

> inside Dockerfile

If you want to use bash features make sure first that you are runnig Bash. `RUN` commands in dockerfile by default sexecute `/bin/sh` (see dockerfile reference documentation) which may not be Bash and may not support Bash arrays.

In this specific case, to be `/bin/sh` compatible, replace `;` for a newline (`tr`) and read it as a newline separated stream or use word-splitting if there are no other whitespaces. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Thanks. This only returns "We", How can i get the whole array?

Comment: `. This only returns "We"` The command shouldn't print anything.

Comment: IFS=';' read -r -a array <<<$IN
echo $array
I am doing this

Comment: `echo $array` will print only first array element. Use `"${array[@]}"`. Might be a good idea to re-read an introduction to bash arrays. In your code above you used `declare -p array`.

Comment: is there a way i print all of them? or have a control on which index to print?